# C++ insert a value in a set of values from a class in a Map

Tags: c++, class, c++11, dictionary, set

I have a map in my class `Cjt_Trets` that contains a string called `rasgo` and a class called `Trets`. In Trets I have a `set<int> id;` that will contain the `id`'s of the people containing that `rasgo`. My problem comes when I try to insert the `id` that the function receives, into that set. How am I supposed to do it?

Here I leave part of the code that can help you understand my situation:

Private of the class Cjt_Trets:

```
private:
  map<string, Trets> mtrets;  
};
```

Private of Trets:

```
private:
  set<int> id;
  string gen;  
};
```

Actual part of the code I don't know how to do:

```
void Cjt_Trets::afegir_tret(int id, string rasgo){    
  mtrets.insert( make_pair<string, Trets> (rasgo, Trets.id.insert(id)) );
}
```

Comment: You describe types and members you use in your example, but a lot of information is missing. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: `id` from Trets is private, you can't access from other class

Comment: `insert` returns a `pair` so you'll have to modify that

Comment: I think it would have been easier to simply create two dummy classes and showed us a [mcve] of a few lines to duplicate the issue, instead of going through a description of a Trets game.

Comment: Purpose of `make_pair` is to not provide template arguments and let deduction happens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
void Cjt_Trets::afegir_tret(int id, string rasgo){    
    auto it = mtrets.find(rasgo) ;  // is rasgo already ion the map?
    if (it == mtrets.end())         // if not insert an empty Trets
        it = mtrets.insert(make_pair(rasgo, Trets()).first ;
    // Now insert the id in the Trets referring to this rasgo
    // TODO it->second is of type Trets and id is private member
    // this needs to be fixed
    it->second.id.insert(id) ; 
}
```

Comment: Even if this were to work, the code could be condensed into just calling `insert` and then use the return value from `insert` to update the id.  Thus there would be no need to call `find` and then test if the item's not found.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a class `Trets`, you can't do `Trets.id`, as id is a non-static member of the class, and even if it were, you'd access it by calling `Trets::id`. However, to insert something into `std::map<string, Trets>`, you'd need and object of `Trets`, and `std::set::insert` returns `std::pair<iterator, bool>`, so you'd need to create or receive from somewhere an actual object of `Trets` to be able to insert it into the `std::map`.